# Django: preventing external query string requests

Tags: django, security, query-string, http-get

I've been doing web development for a few months now and keep having this nagging problem. It is typical for pages to request content with a query string which usually contains meaningful data such as an id in the database. An example would be a link such as:

```
http://www.example.com/posts?id=5
```

I've been trying to think of a good strategy to prevent users from manually entering a value for the id without having accessed it from a link--I'd only wish to acknowledge requests that were made by links presented on my website. Also, the website may not have an authentication system and allows for anonymous browsing; that being said, the information isn't particularly sensitive but still I don't like the idea of not being able to control access to certain information. One option, I suppose, would be to use HTTP POST requests for these kind of pages -- I don't believe a user can simulate a post request but I may be wrong.

Furthermore, the user could place any arbitrary number for the id and end up requesting a record that doesn't exist in the database. Of course, I could validate the requested id but then I would be wasting resources to accommodate this check.

Any thoughts? I'm working with django but a general strategy for any programming language would be good. Thanks.

Comment: A user can simulate any kind of request a browser could.

Comment: To prevent users from using unwanted methods of supplying data, there is a CSRF, which could be used in POST request, so it should work in GET requests too (i hope). But to be correct - it's not a good thing to depend on a parameter requested in URL. It's not a waste of time and resources to check, whether the database item is present. This could lead to a serious problems sometime in the future.

Comment: "...I don't like the idea of not being able to control access to certain information". How do you know what information is "certain" and what not? As I see the best way is to add `private` boolean field to your model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, choosing between GET and POST: A user can simulate any kind of request, so POST will not help you there. When choosing between the two it is best to *decide based on the action the user is taking* or how they are interacting with your content. Are they getting a page or sending you data (a form is the obvious example)? For your case of retrieving some sort of post, GET is appropriate.

Also worth noting, GET is the correct choice if the content is appropriate for bookmarking. Serving a URL based solely on the referrer -- as you say, "prevent users from manually entering a value for the id without having accessed it from a link" -- is a terrible idea. This will cause you innumerable headaches and it is probably not a nice experience for the user.

As general principle, **avoid relying on the primary key of a database record**. That key (id=5 in your case) should be treated purely as an auto-increment field to prevent record collisions, i.e. you are guaranteed to always have a unique field for all records in the table. That ID field is a backend utility. Don't expose it to your users and don't rely on it yourself.

If you can't use ID, what do you use? A common idiom is using the **date** of the record, a **slug** or both. If you are dealing with posts, use the published/created date. Then add a text field that will hold URL friendly and descriptive words. Call it a slug and read about Django's [models.SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) for more information. Also, see the URL of an article on basically any news site. Your final URL will look something like `http://www.example.com/posts/2012/01/19/this-is-cool/`

Now your URL is friendly on the eyes, has Google-fu SEO benefits, is bookmark-able and isn't guessable. Because you aren't relying on a back-end database fixed arbitrary ID, you have the freedom to...restore a backup db dump, move databases, change the auto-increment number ID to a UUID hash, whatever. Only your database will care, not you as a programmer and not your users.

Oh and don't over-worry about a user "requesting a record that doesn't exist" or "validating the requested id"...you have to do that anyway. It isn't consuming unnecessary resources. It is how a database-backed website works. You have to connect the request to the data. If the request is incorrect, you 404. Your webserver does it for non-existent URLs and you'll need to do it for non-existent data. Checkout Django's [get_object_or_404()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) for ideas/implementation.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me some direction.

Comment: When using slugs how do you guarantee there won't be any collisions (i.e. two identical slugs for different ids)? I guess finer granularity in the time stamp would do it.

Comment: @UmairAhmad good question. Add a unique constraint on the slug field or a unique constraint across both slug and date. Django has a [unique_for_date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#unique-for-date) model field option for just this use case.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I know of to do this effectively, since there is basically no way to stop someone from forging any request.

The first is not to use bare IDs in the query parameters. Instead, generate a large random number, and make the link out of that. You will have to keep a table in your database mapping your random numbers to the actual IDs they represent, and you will have to clean the table eventually. This is fairly simple to implement, but requires some storage space, and some management of the stored data occasionally.

The second method is to sign the data when you make a link. By appending a cryptographic signature to the data, and verifying the signature when a request is made, you ensure that only your web service could possibly have created the link. Even if the request itself is 'forged' -- perhaps bookmarked, written down, copy-and-pasted into another browser -- you know that your site has already authorized that URL.

To do this, you need to create a Message Authentication Code (MAC) with the data that you are signing (say, just the 'id' value, or possibly the id and the time that you signed the data) and with a secret key that you keep only on your server.

In your view, then, you take the id value (or id and timestamp, if that's what you're using) and you construct the MAC again, and see if they match. If there's any difference, you reject the request as having been tampered with.

Look at the python docs for the [hmac module](http://docs.python.org/library/hmac.html), as well as the [hashlib module](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) for all of the details.

You could generate a link in python like this:

settings.py:

```
hmac_secret_key = '12345'
```

views.py:

```
import time, hmac, hashlib
from django.conf import settings

def some_view(request):
    ...
    id = 5
    time = int(time.time())
    mac = hmac.new(
        settings.hmac_secret_key,
        '%d/%d' % (id, time),
        hashlib.sha1)
    url = 'http://www.example.com/posts/id=%d&ts=%d&mac=%s' % (
        id, time, mac.hexdigest())
    # Now return a template with that url in it somewhere
```

To verify it in another view, you would use code like this: (warning, warning, not robust, lots of error checking still to do)

```
def posts_view(request):
    id = int(request.GET['id'])
    ts = int(request.GET['ts'])
    mac_from_url = request.GET['mac']

    computed_mac = hmac.new(
        settings.hmac_secret_key,
        '%d/%d' % (id, time),
        hashlib.sha1)

    if mac_from_url <> computed_mac:
        raise SomeSecurityException()

    # Now you know that the request is legit. 
    # You can check the timestamp here, too, if you like.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the correct way of doing it but maybe you can save the url he is going to be redirected after the `GET` request into the session, and write a `decorator` so that if the session has that url take him to that page. else give a 404 error or something.